# How can i share image on whatsapp in mobile through website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have e-commerce website having platform of shopify. I want to share image on whatsapp in mo
    Code :bile.I referred most of the forums but i don't get what i want.

I have whatsapp button on product page in mobile view so that any can share product through website.I have following code which only shares text not image.

```
Code :

<a id="product-whatsapp" href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website: " data-href="" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s"><i class="display: inline;"></i></a></div>
```

I want to share only that same image clicking on the same product page.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You forgot attach the code.

Comment: Code :

<a id="product-whatsapp" href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website: " data-href="" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s"><i class="display: inline;"></i></a></div>

Comment: please update your post so we can evade confusion :)